# Mapbox.js tooltips - position over marker, but don't follow mouse

Tags: tooltip, mapbox, tilemill

Is there a way to get Mapbox.js tooltips to show when you're hovering over a marker without following the mouse around? I just want it to stay put when I hover.

I am using the following code on my map:

```
var map = L.map("impact-map")
    .setView([20, 80], 3)
    .addLayer(L.mapbox.tileLayer("hotchkissmade.in_impact", {
        detectRetina: true
    }));

var myGridLayer = L.mapbox.gridLayer('hotchkissmade.in_impact').addTo( map );
var myGridControl = L.mapbox.gridControl(myGridLayer, { 
    follow: true
}).addTo( map );
```

I am using the `follow:true` from the example [here](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/movetip/).

*Disclaimer: I know there may be more flexibility outside of `gridControl` but I like having my tooltips from Tilemill as I don't want to load the data in the browser twice, since I'm basing the tooltip data off the layer making the markers on my map in Tilemill*

Comment: what about not setting `follow` to `true`...?

Comment: @sfletche that would make the tooltip stick to the upper right corner.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible with a `gridControl` - you can have tooltips either follow the mouse or stay in a specific location, but unlike `L.mapbox.featureLayer`, there is no actual marker, polygon, or feature you're hovering over - the geometry is not pushed to the client - so, there would be no 'anchor' for the tooltip to stay on.

Comment: Is it possible to use `L.mapbox.featureLayer` to use the same data that `gridControl` uses to bake up my own?

Comment: The two are different: gridControl and featureLayer use UTFGrid and GeoJSON respectively. It's similar to how PDFs are vector, and images are raster. You would need to include source data directly in order to use featureLayer.